# Using mutually exclusive group arguments as flags of function

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I've written the following program where objective is to list items of a particular type based on the mutually exclusive argument.

```
def run():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='List Items')
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    sub_parsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='list commands')
    listItems_parser = sub_parsers.add_parser('listitem', help='List items in the directory')
    listItems_parser.add_argument('-s','--source_dir', help='Source Directory',required = True)
    listItems_parser = group.add_argument('-t','--tonic',help='List Tonic', action ='store_true')
    listItems_parser = group.add_argument('-c','--capsule',help='List Capsule', action ='store_true')
    listItems_parser.set_defaults(func=run_iList_commands)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.func(args)
```

But when I run the program, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: '_StoreTrueAction' object has no attribute 'set_defaults'
```

Please help me understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement creates a parser which you assign to `listItemss_parser`

```
listItems_parser = sub_parsers.add_parser('listitem', help='List items in the directory')
```

this creates an argument (`Action`) in that parser.

```
listItems_parser.add_argument('-s','--source_dir', help='Source Directory',required = True)
```

This also creates an argument, `Action` object, but in the `group` (which was earlier defined as part of the main `parser`.

And for some unknown reason you assign this object to the same variable name that you used earlier for a subparser.  Why?  Are you trying to add this argument to that subparser?

```
listItems_parser = group.add_argument('-t','--tonic',help='List Tonic', action ='store_true')
```

same type of argument assignment:

```
listItems_parser = group.add_argument('-c','--capsule',help='List Capsule', action ='store_true')
```

Remember, `listItems_parser` is now an `Action`, not a `parser` - hence the error.

```
listItems_parser.set_defaults(func=run_iList_commands)
```

I suspect you want to do something like:

```
group = listItems_parser.add_multually....
group.add_argument(...)
group.add_argument(...)
```

in other words, define the `group` to be in the subparser.

---

```
listItems_parser.set_defaults(func=run_iList_commands)
args = parser.parse_args(['listitem',...])
```

When 'listitem' is in the commandline, the `listItems_parser` is run, and it sets the defaults, and values, for all the arguments defined for it. And because of this `set_defaults` command, the `args` namespace will include a `func` item.  (I think this is illustrated in the docs).

In other words, `args` will look something like (print it):

```
Namespace(func=run_iList_commands, source_dir=..., tonic=..., capsule=....)
```

So this line:

```
args.func(args)
```

ends up calling `run_iList_commands` function, and it gets, as argument this namespace.  Inside this function it can do:

```
args.source.dir...
if args.tonic:
   etc
```

I strongly recommend running this, or something simpler, in an interactive session, and print various values.  It's easier to see what is going on in such a session, than it is to explain them.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wanted to know that how the function run_iList_commands will check that which flag is true.